# Open Session in View Alternate

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, orm, lazy-loading

We are in process of developing a web application using stuts2 (mvc layer),spring 3.x (DI ,transaction demarcation,other relevant stuff) and Hibernate 3.x (Persistence).

Like any other web application using such or similar platform one has to take care of case when main logic of the action has been completed, and therefore, the Hibernate Session has already been closed and the database transaction has ended,one common problem we have to take care when exception we get is: LazyInitializationException: Session has been closed .

There are various way to solve this problem and one of the widely accepted solution is 
**Open Session in View** pattern.
As we are using spring so we can easily utilize spring out of the box support for this.

Is there ant other good alternate for this pattern, by asking this i am not looking for a alternate solution but want to do a comparative study what other good and equally efficient approaches are available to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance
Umesh

Answer (score 1):

OSIV seems to always cause people issues.  Here's a strategy which has worked well for me:

1. All Hibernate associations are marked LAZY
2. DAO get methods all take a Boolean `loadChildren`; if yes, initialize the child associations for the get'ed entity
3. Depending on whether child associations are needed for the particular request or not, the Controller passes `loadChildren` as T or F to the service and the DAO layer
4. View-layer access has what it needs to traverse associations without worrying about whether they are initialized or not